# Is there a replacement for method or function Frac in .NET that will take DateTime parameter?

Tags: .net, math, datetimepicker, delphi-prism, fractions

I am working with Delphi Prism for .NET. I need to be able to take DateTime Value and separate the time from the date. I can do that on Win32 Delphi by using Frac function. I can't seem to find anything similar to that for .NET. Do you know if anything exists for that?

Having not much luck, I wrote my own Frac method for .NET, but it only wants Double or Decimal values to run not DateTime. It seems .NET doesn't treat DateTime Value as a Float or Decimal. Is that true? If that is true, my Frac method won't work.

```
method Frac(theValue:Double):Double;
begin
    result := (theValue-math.Truncate(theValue));
end;
```

I have the datetimepicker set to Time format and retrieve the value and set it a datetime variable but only want the time not the date.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ChrisShouts yes it does. Doesn't it? That's why I had to post a question in Stackoverflow. :) On Win32 Delphi DateTime is automatically converted to large float or decimal. Date being the whole number and decimal part being the time. Well, I guess I have to write my program differently when it comes to processing date and time for .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything wrong with [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) and [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx)?

(In fact, the answer is [yes, there *is* quite a lot wrong with `DateTime`](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), but that's a different matter... of course if you're interested in using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) from Delphi, I'd be very interested in hearing from you...)

Comment: @ Jon, TimeOfDay is of TimeSpan Type not the actual time as in 11:03AM. My program doesn't really care for the Date part of the DateTime value.

Comment: @digitalanalog: You could always add that to some arbitrary date if you want. The point is that those two properties split the date from the time. If your code doesn't care about the date part, then does it matter what it is? If it doesn't matter what it is, why do you need to split it at all?

Comment: @ Jon, True. I can ignore the date. So, how do you set or retrieve actual time from DateTimePicker?